# How to check if URL exists (and detect if it's a template error page)?

Tags: http, curl, web

I used the curl command from here [How to check if an URL exists with the shell and probably curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199059/how-to-check-if-an-url-exists-with-the-shell-and-probably-curl)

but it doesn't work if the website has a generic error page like "Sorry, we are unable to find that page".

How to detect such pages automatically?

Test URL

> http://www.nytimes.com/2013/09/18/us/washington-navy-yard-shootings.html

^ page exists

> http://www.nytimes.com/2013/09/18/us/washington-navy-yard.html

^ page does not exist

Answer (score 1):

To check is the page is valid:

```
curl -s --head http://your_url/ | head -n 1 | grep 200
```

or you can grep `404` to check if "page doesn't exist"

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't always work. Please see the test URL in edited question.

Comment: @user13107 not true, if you'll try to "grep" 200 on that second URL you posted - you'll fail. You're actually getting HTTP 303 (see other) for that URL! stick to "grep 200" and you'll get a result returned for valid URLs only

Comment: Hi, I'm getting no output for either pages when I do `grep 200`. Did you get different output for them both?