# Check if a remote file exists in bash

Tags: bash, wget, gnu-parallel

I am downloading files with this script:

```
parallel --progress -j16 -a ./temp/img-url.txt 'wget -nc -q -P ./images/ {}; wget -nc -q -P ./images/ {.}_{001..005}.jpg'
```

Would it be possible to not download files, just check them on the remote side and if exists create a dummy file instead of downloading?

Something like:

```
if wget --spider $url 2>/dev/null; then
  #touch img.file
fi
```

should work, but I don't know how to combine this code with GNU Parallel.

Edit:

Based on Ole's answer I wrote this piece of code:

```
#!/bin/bash
do_url() {
  url="$1"
  wget -q -nc  --method HEAD "$url" && touch ./images/${url##*/}   
  #get filename from $url
  url2=${url##*/}
  wget -q -nc  --method HEAD ${url%.jpg}_{001..005}.jpg && touch ./images/${url2%.jpg}_{001..005}.jpg
}
export -f do_url

parallel --progress -a urls.txt do_url {}
```

It works, but it fails for some files. I can not find consistency why it works for some files, why it fails for others. Maybe it has something with the last filename. Second wget tries to access the currect url, but the touch command after that simply does not create the desidered file. First wget always (correctly) downloads the main image without the _001.jpg, _002.jpg.

Example urls.txt:

http://host.com/092401.jpg (works correctly, _001.jpg.._005.jpg are downloaded)
http://host.com/HT11019.jpg (not works, only the main image is downloaded)

Comment: Use the `--method HEAD` to send a `HEAD` request instead of a `GET` request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199059/how-to-check-if-an-url-exists-with-the-shell-and-probably-curl

Comment: @iamauser Are you serious? In that question where is the word about checking sequence of files on the remote side?

Comment: Yes, I am. I think your question should rather be how to loop over a sequence of files, because that's the input to each call by `wget/curl`.

Comment: It is not nice to completely change your question after a few answers have been provided. This makes most of the answers provided here to look wrong. However, the problem is that you changed the question after they were provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is pretty hard to understand what it is you *really* want to accomplish. Let me try to rephrase your question.

> I have `urls.txt` containing:
>
> ```
> http://example.com/dira/foo.jpg
> http://example.com/dira/bar.jpg
> http://example.com/dirb/foo.jpg
> http://example.com/dirb/baz.jpg
> http://example.org/dira/foo.jpg
> ```
>
> On `example.com` these URLs exist:
>
> ```
> http://example.com/dira/foo.jpg
> http://example.com/dira/foo_001.jpg
> http://example.com/dira/foo_003.jpg
> http://example.com/dira/foo_005.jpg
> http://example.com/dira/bar_000.jpg
> http://example.com/dira/bar_002.jpg
> http://example.com/dira/bar_004.jpg
> http://example.com/dira/fubar.jpg
> http://example.com/dirb/foo.jpg
> http://example.com/dirb/baz.jpg
> http://example.com/dirb/baz_001.jpg
> http://example.com/dirb/baz_005.jpg
> ```
>
> On `example.org` these URLs exist:
>
> ```
> http://example.org/dira/foo_001.jpg
> ```
>
> Given `urls.txt` I want to generate the combinations with _001.jpg .. _005.jpg in addition to the original URL. E.g.:
>
> ```
> http://example.com/dira/foo.jpg
> ```
>
> becomes:
>
> ```
> http://example.com/dira/foo.jpg
> http://example.com/dira/foo_001.jpg
> http://example.com/dira/foo_002.jpg
> http://example.com/dira/foo_003.jpg
> http://example.com/dira/foo_004.jpg
> http://example.com/dira/foo_005.jpg
> ```
>
> Then I want to test if these URLs exist without downloading the file. As there are many URLs I want to do this in parallel.
>
> If the URL exists I want an empty file created.
>
> (Version 1): I want the empty file created in a the similar directory structure in the dir `images`. This is needed because some of the images have the same name, but in different dirs.
>
> So the files created should be:
>
> ```
> images/http:/example.com/dira/foo.jpg
> images/http:/example.com/dira/foo_001.jpg
> images/http:/example.com/dira/foo_003.jpg
> images/http:/example.com/dira/foo_005.jpg
> images/http:/example.com/dira/bar_000.jpg
> images/http:/example.com/dira/bar_002.jpg
> images/http:/example.com/dira/bar_004.jpg
> images/http:/example.com/dirb/foo.jpg
> images/http:/example.com/dirb/baz.jpg
> images/http:/example.com/dirb/baz_001.jpg
> images/http:/example.com/dirb/baz_005.jpg
> images/http:/example.org/dira/foo_001.jpg
> ```
>
> (Version 2): I want the empty file created in the dir `images`. This can be done because all the images have unique names.
>
> So the files created should be:
>
> ```
> images/foo.jpg
> images/foo_001.jpg
> images/foo_003.jpg
> images/foo_005.jpg
> images/bar_000.jpg
> images/bar_002.jpg
> images/bar_004.jpg
> images/baz.jpg
> images/baz_001.jpg
> images/baz_005.jpg
> ```
>
> (Version 3): I want the empty file created in the dir `images` called the name from `urls.txt`. This can be done because only one of _001.jpg .. _005.jpg exists.
>
> ```
> images/foo.jpg
> images/bar.jpg
> images/baz.jpg
> ```

```
#!/bin/bash

do_url() {
  url="$1"

  # Version 1:
  # If you want to keep the folder structure from the server (similar to wget -m):
  wget -q --method HEAD "$url" && mkdir -p images/"$2" && touch images/"$url"

  # Version 2:
  # If all the images have unique names and you want all images in a single dir
  wget -q --method HEAD "$url" && touch images/"$3"

  # Version 3:
  # If all the images have unique names when _###.jpg is removed and you want all images in a single dir
  wget -q --method HEAD "$url" && touch images/"$4"

}
export -f do_url

parallel do_url {1.}{2} {1//} {1/.}{2} {1/} :::: urls.txt ::: .jpg _{001..005}.jpg
```

GNU Parallel takes a few ms per job. When your jobs are this short, the overhead will affect the timing. If none of your CPU cores are running at 100% you can run more jobs in parallel:

```
parallel -j0 do_url {1.}{2} {1//} {1/.}{2} {1/} :::: urls.txt ::: .jpg _{001..005}.jpg
```

You can also "unroll" the loop. This will save 5 overheads per URL:

```
do_url() {
  url="$1"
  # Version 2:
  # If all the images have unique names and you want all images in a single dir
  wget -q --method HEAD "$url".jpg && touch images/"$url".jpg
  wget -q --method HEAD "$url"_001.jpg && touch images/"$url"_001.jpg
  wget -q --method HEAD "$url"_002.jpg && touch images/"$url"_002.jpg
  wget -q --method HEAD "$url"_003.jpg && touch images/"$url"_003.jpg
  wget -q --method HEAD "$url"_004.jpg && touch images/"$url"_004.jpg
  wget -q --method HEAD "$url"_005.jpg && touch images/"$url"_005.jpg
}
export -f do_url

parallel -j0 do_url {.} :::: urls.txt
```

Finally you can run more than 250 jobs: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Running-more-than-250-jobs-workaround

Comment: It is not possible to save all images into images/ directory? I have a long URL and this script creates a weird folder structure.

Comment: Added `images`.

Comment: I needed the "Version 2". It works fine, thank you. I made a little benchmark and I am disappointed in the speed. It is much slower than downloading files, if you are interested, here is the result: https://pastebin.ca/3971248. What do you think, where is the bottleneck?

Comment: With 250 jobs (-j0) the running time is now halfed, but unfortunately it is still slower compared to wget --no-clog (do not download if exists). But it is a great answer and I will definitely use it in the future. Something is weird with the latest example:  $ ls images/
_001.jpg  _002.jpg  _003.jpg  _004.jpg  _005.jpg.

Answer (score 6):

You may use `curl` instead to check if the URLs you are parsing are there without downloading any file as such:

```
if curl --head --fail --silent "$url" >/dev/null; then
    touch .images/"${url##*/}"
fi
```

Explanation:

- `--fail` will make the exit status nonzero on a failed request.
- `--head` will avoid downloading the file contents
- `--silent` will avoid status or errors from being emitted by the check itself.

To solve the "looping" issue, you can do:

```
urls=( "${url%.jpg}"_{001..005}.jpg )
for url in "${urls[@]}"; do
    if curl --head --silent --fail "$url" > /dev/null; then
        touch .images/${url##*/}
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see, your question isn't really about how to use `wget` to test for the existence of a file, but rather on how to perform correct looping in a shell script.

Here is a simple solution for that:

```
urls=( "${url%.jpg}"_{001..005}.jpg )
for url in "${urls[@]}"; do
    if wget -q --method=HEAD "$url"; then
        touch .images/${url##*/}
    fi
done
```

What this does is that it invokes Wget with the `--method=HEAD` option. With the `HEAD` request, the server will simply report back whether the file exists or not, without returning any data.

Of course, with a large data set this is pretty inefficient. You're creating a new connection to the server for every file you're trying. Instead, as suggested in the other answer, you could use GNU Wget2. With wget2, you can test all of these in parallel, and use the new `--stats-server` option to find a list of all the files and the specific return code that the server provided. For example:

```
$ wget2 --spider --progress=none -q --stats-site example.com/{,1,2,3}                                                             
Site Statistics:

  http://example.com:
    Status    No. of docs
       404              3
         http://example.com/3  0 bytes (identity) : 0 bytes (decompressed), 238ms (transfer) : 238ms (response)
         http://example.com/1  0 bytes (gzip) : 0 bytes (decompressed), 241ms (transfer) : 241ms (response)
         http://example.com/2  0 bytes (identity) : 0 bytes (decompressed), 238ms (transfer) : 238ms (response)
       200              1
         http://example.com/  0 bytes (identity) : 0 bytes (decompressed), 231ms (transfer) : 231ms (response)
```

You can even get this data printed as a CSV or JSON for easier parsing

Comment: @Finally I was able to compile Wget2. For a quick test I runned: wget2 --spider --progress=none  --stats-site=csv:stat.csv ${url%.jpg}_{001..005}.jpg. It queries URL's fine (example.com/hello_001.jpg, etc.), but in stat.csv is only one, the last query + I think for main image (exampe.com/hello.jpg)) I still need to run Wget2 one more time.

Comment: I am imagining if that Wget2 should work faster than Wget&Parallel. Currently Wget&Parallel&TouchDummyFile is slower than Wget&Parallel&DownloadFiles. Benchmark results are under @OleTange answer.

Comment: It is possible that the parallel+touch is slower than just downloading the files if the images are very small (~5kB). This is because you still need to make a new connection to the server for each file you're testing and then start a new process. This is sometimes slower than just downloading said file. Wget2 should indeed be faster in this case since it needs to establish the connection exactly once.

Comment: The issue with the stats that you see is a bug. I'll make a report and it should be fixed within a day or two. Till then, if you don't use json or csv, you can still see the full stats

Comment: Thank you, I'll report back after the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Just loop over the names?

```
for uname in ${url%.jpg}_{001..005}.jpg
do
  if wget --spider $uname 2>/dev/null; then
    touch ./images/${uname##*/}
  fi
done
```

Comment: I asked this question, because I don't want to download any files just check on the remote side and make a local dummy file (with same name) if exists.

Answer (score -2):

You could send a command via ssh to see if the remote file exists and cat it if it does:

```
ssh your_host 'test -e "somefile" && cat "somefile"' > somefile
```

Could also try scp which supports glob expressions and recursion.

Comment: Nope, remote host is http only.

Comment: curl -I could tell you if the file exists